# Creating a pay slip in PDF format using progress 4gl and email to employee

Tags: progress-4gl

I have a requirement to create a pdf file that includes the salary slip details like (DA,HRA,Basic,Leave taken.... etc) by taking a leave taken as an input value from update able browser and generate a report in form of pdf that will be send to employee as well as bank to get credit the amount to thier respective salary account.

Comment: I am doing with Asp.net and crystal reports. If interested, I can let you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a PDF document from within Progress, you can use PDFinclude (a Free Libre Open Source Software piece of code) to do so.  See http://www.oehive.org/pdfinclude to get started.